# Transpor dados de forma automática

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Estou com o seguinte problema, preciso criar um "robô" que leia os dados de uma determinada célula no Excel e digite esses dados em um outro software (software próprio da empresa em que trabalho), porém ele tem de "digitar" exatamente os dados que foram lidos dessa célula nesse SW, tendo em vista que esse programa da empresa não  aceita que dados sejam colados nele. Já tenho algo em vba em que consigo posicionar o mouse exatamente no lugar que preciso nesse software e enviar um clique para que os dados sejam inseridos no software, o problema fica por conta de "digitar" os dados lidos na planilha em Excel dentro dele (respeitando também os espaços), existe alguma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Não me lembro de formas nativas de VBA para interagir com outros softwares não-Windows. A não ser que o software da empresa esteja programado em VBA... ou talvez alguma outra programação do Windows. O que eu sugiro é a utilização de outros softwares _3rd party_... Um deles é o AutoIT, [que pode ser utilizado em VBA](http://www.amarindaz.com/autoit-in-excel-vba_17/), em que um exemplo de como declarar pode também ser visto [aqui](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/16956-autoitx-with-excelvba/).

Comment: Obrigado Daniel, irei verificar essa alternativa!

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde.
Para "digitar" você deve utilizar a Instrução SendKeys.
Essa instrução, funciona apenas com variáveis string.

O código ficaria assim:

```
Dim strvar as string
strvar=cells(1,1).value
(sua macro para clicar no campo certo)
SendKeys strvar
```